# Binding to a value that gets updated in the ViewModel in MVVM?

Tags: .net, mvvm

I'm new to MVVM.

I have a label in my view that looks like this:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Path=ClockTime}" />
```

And my ViewModel looks like:

```
Public Class MainWindowViewModel
  Inherits ViewModelBase

  Dim strClockTime As String
  Dim dstDispatcherTimer As New Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer

  Public Sub New()
    AddHandler dstDispatcherTimer.Tick, AddressOf TimeDelegate
    dstDispatcherTimer.Interval = New TimeSpan(0, 0, 1)
    dstDispatcherTimer.Start()
  End Sub

  Private Sub TimeDelegate(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    strClockTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy h:mm:ss tt")
  End Sub

  Public ReadOnly Property ClockTime As String
    Get
      Return strClockTime
    End Get
  End Property

End Class
```

My problem is that the label doesn't update dynamically with the thread in the ViewModel.  Is there a simple way to let the View know this value is dynamic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on what Todd said you should update your code like this
you need ViewModelBase to look something like this

```
Public class ViewModelBase Inherits INotifyPropertyChanged
  protected Sub OnPropertyChanged(PropertyName as string)
    if PropertyChanged is not nothing then
      PropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName)
    end if 
  End Sub
End Class
```

and then modify your view model like so:

```
  Private Sub TimeDelegate(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    ClockTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy h:mm:ss tt")
  End Sub

  Public Property ClockTime As String
    Get
      Return strClockTime
    End Get
    Private Set
      strClockTime = value
      OnPropertyChanged("ClockTime")
    End Set
  End Property
```

Notice that i'm assigning to ClockTime and when that gets set WPF is notified that ClockTime has changed

Answer (score 4):

You need to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface in your ViewModel, and raise the PropertyChanged event when you set ClockTime